# why not found device obj?

Tags: c, kernel, driver, systems-programming

I write driver .
Creates an Device Object (name = ICOCTL_1) when the service starts but getlastError function return not_foun_file(code 2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy7tP.png)

```
 void CUserAppDlg::OnBnClickedbtncreate(){


deviceHandle =  CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\IOCTL_1", GENERIC_ALL, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM, 0);

 DWORD data = GetLastError();

  TCHAR s[100];

 _stprintf_s(s, _T("%X"), data);



 MessageBox(s);}
```

Comment: Why do you call `GetLastError`? You don't even check if the function call succeeded.

Comment: I checked that the handle is returning invalid status

Comment: \Device\xyz are not exposed to Win32, they are internal NT paths. If there's a symlink to \??\  you will be able to access them through \\.\ BUT the NT namespace root is exposed via global root. so you can use \\.\GLOBALROOT\Device\IOCTL_1

Comment: You already asked the question about the very similar code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374167/why-not-found-my-device-but-exist-in-winobj. If you want to incorporate additional information to the question, then just edit it. Re-asking the same question is very discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why not found my device but exist in winObj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374167/why-not-found-my-device-but-exist-in-winobj)